# Error when calling a Entitie made by entity framework from edmx model

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6, entities

I'm trying to access my dbEntities that was created through the ADO.Net Entity Data Model, but when I try to access it, it "finds" the database tables but it gives a certain error that I will put immediately below, I already tried everything , change the Metadata, create an application of 0 and tested and it did not work, can anyone help me?

This is a new web application that I'm trying to develop, the front part is all ready, the only problem is this connection to the database, where I've tried a lot, like creating another project, and some tutorials, but even so it does not work, the database I'm trying to access is not local, it's from a server, and I was wondering if I would have a MySQL configuration that might be blocking the SELECT or something

```
try
{
    dbEntitiescontext = new dbEntities();

    var listDTO = new List<CompanyDTO>();

    var list = context.company.ToList();

    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        listDTO.Add(new CompanyDTO().ToDTO(item));
    }


    return listDTO ;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw new Exception(e.Message);
}
```

Currently it returns me the following error:

> 'dbEntities.company.Local' threw an exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException'

Comment: Which line throws the error? 
My guess is this one 
var list = context.company.ToList(); 
look at the context, maybe it is a typo but "dbEntitiescontext" was in question

Comment: Already resolved, i maked 2 times the same edmx in different projects in same folder, for some reason, when i excluded one, the visual studio dont deleted the app config string connection, and the new model used the old string connection.